# Help in understanding inequality involving gradient

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f \in C_0^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, i'm reading a text and the author stated without proof that if we fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ then for every $y \in \mathbb{R}^N$ we have
$$|f(x-y)-f(x)| \leq |\nabla f|_{\infty}|y|. $$

How to prove this inequality? I don't need a full solution, every hint on how to begin will be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: mean-value theorem?

Comment: That should be $|f(x-y)-f(x)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct inequality is $$|f(x-y)-f(x)|\le||\nabla f||_\infty|y|.$$

To prove this, define $$g(t)=f(x-ty),$$so $f(x-y)-f(x)=g(1)-g(0)$. Apply the mean-value theorem to $g(1)-g(0)$, using the chain rule to write $g'(\xi)$ in terms of $\nabla f$.